# how to test reduce function inside exports function Jest(react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, redux

I have a reducer in react which I am testing I want to test the return value of a reduce inside the exports default function. And I'm not sure how to get access to the reduce inside that function.

MyReducer:

```
exports default function myReducer({
 people = [0,1,2];
 people.reduce(function(sum, peeps){
 return sum + peeps;
 }0);
 return "hey";
})
```

In jest test:

```
import myReducer from 'myReducer';
expectedPeeps = 3;
expect(Something needs to go here).toEqual(expectedPeeps);
```

I need to figure out how to get the return value of people.reduce. I can get "hey" by just invoking myReducer(). But how do I get the return value of people.reduce in my test! ?thanks in advance peeps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have several syntax issues in MyReducer. I think it should look like this:

```js
export default function myReducer() {
  const people = [0,1,2];
  people.reduce(function(sum, peeps){
    return sum + peeps;
  }, 0);
  return "hey";
}
```

If you need to test the reduce by itself, you could move it into its own function and export it:

```js
export function reducePeople(people) {
  return people.reduce(function(sum, peeps){
    return sum + peeps;
  }, 0);
}

export default function myReducer() {
  people = [0,1,2];
  reducePeople(people);
  return "hey";
}
```

And import and test it in your tests:

```js
import { reducePeople } from 'myReducer';
expectedPeeps = 3;
expect(reducePeople([0,1,2])).toEqual(expectedPeeps);
```